# Ionic 3 - Search bar using Ionic 3, PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, angular, ionic3

I'm working on an app using Ionic 3, PHP and SQL Server database for the backend. I'm trying to implement search bar. I had gone through several examples on the internet but did not work for me. Please check the code below and help.

**Employee.ts file code:**

```
loadData()
{
    var link = this.baseURI + "retrieve-employee-details.php";

    this.http.get(link)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data =>
    {
        console.log("EMPLOYEES: ", data);
        this.employees = data;
    });
}

initializeItems(){
    this.employeeList = this.employees;
}

getItem(ev: any){
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.employeeList = this.employeeList.filter((item) => {
        return (item.FirstName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())>-1);
      })
    }
}
```

**Employee.html file code:**

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItem($event)">
   </ion-searchbar>


<div>
    <ion-grid class="client">
        <ion-row wrap class="gridHeading">
          <ion-col col-7 class="gridHeading" align="center">EMPLOYEE</ion-col>
          <ion-col col-5 class="gridHeading" align="center">MOBILE</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row wrap *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="gridCol">
          <ion-col col-7 class="gridCol" (click)="selectEmployee($event, employee)">{{ employee.FirstName + " " + employee.LastName }}</ion-col>
          <ion-col col-5 class="gridCol" (click)="call(employee.Mobile)"><ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon> {{ employee.Mobile }}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</div>
```

I want to search name and display all the employees related to that name in a gridview.
[image: Check this image for design]

**Employees Array Structure:**

[image: Employees array structure]

Comment: can you share the employees array structure please

Comment: Yes please check the question, at the bottom I have displayed employees array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have firstName in the employee object. can you try editing the object model such that it contains a key called FirstName